# Using networkx bfs_tree to obtain a list of nodes of a directed graph in BFS order

Tags: python, graph, networkx, breadth-first-search

For example, given:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_path([0, 1])
G.add_path([0, 2])
G.add_path([0, 3])

G.add_path([1, 11])
G.add_path([1, 12])

G.add_path([2, 21])
G.add_path([2, 22])

G.add_path([3, 31])
G.add_path([3, 32])
```

I want this:
`0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 21, 22, 31, 32`

Why does the networkx documentation of `bfs_tree` actually uses `bfs_edges` in its example? And not `bfs_tree`? The key line from the example given in the [bfs_tree documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/traversal/breadth_first_search.html):

```
print(list(nx.bfs_edges(G,0)))
```

Using bfs_edge instead, e.g. via `print(list(nx.algorithms.bfs_tree(G, 0).edges()))` seems to result in the same list as returned by the example code but is obviously more complicated. Can I use `bfs_tree()` in a simpler way to obtain a list of `_nodes_` of a directed graph in BFS order?

Of course, I could iterate the list returned from `bfs_tree` or `bfs_edges` and only take the second element. But isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not flatten the list of edge tuples (each 2 nodes), and then take the `set` of nodes to ensure uniqueness?

```
list(set(sum(list(nx.algorithms.bfs_tree(G, 0).edges()), ())))
```

In your hypothetical solution, you would ignore the `0` node, and it would not be included in your output.

Or you could use the `bfs_successors()` method to get a dict of nodes (passing in the `0` node) and take the  `values`.

```
[0].extend(nx.algorithms.bfs_successors(G, 0).values())
# Get your first, node, and extend with a list of all successor nodes in BFS order
```

Comment: Ok I get it. There is no way to get the nodes directly. I need to go by the edges. Then, your suggestion 

[0].extend(nx.algorithms.bfs_successors(G, 0).values()) is neat. 
Thank you!

Comment: Hi! I tried it too but it seems not to be working. I got this error: _bfs = [start].extend(nx.algorithms.bfs_successors(maze,start).values())
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'values'_ . Do you have any idea of why? start is made of a (0, 0) tuple and maze is the name of the graph

Comment: @hellomynameisA Yes, and `[0].extend` would yield no result too. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of Networkx 2.6.2, this actually works:

```py
[0] + [successor for successors in dict(nx.bfs_successors(G, 0)).values() for successor in successors]
```

---

**Edit.** My original suggestion:

```py
[0] + sum(dict(nx.bfs_successors(G, 0)).values(), [])
```

The `sum(l ,[])` idiom flattens the list, but is quadratic. Discussion on [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists).